# If Qc> Kc how can forward reaction can take place

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, everyday-chemistry, equilibrium, physical-organic-chemistry

If Qc>Kc then there will be a net backward reaction but still forward reaction will take place. My problem is if Qc>Kc forward reaction will become non spontaneous right. So how can that happen, does it like the gibbs free energy which released during backward reaction absorbs by products for forward reaction?

Comment: Please define Qc and Kc

Comment: Molecules do not know Qc/Kc ratio. nothing tells them "Now you can react." nor "Now you cannot." // Trolleybuses do not spontaneously climb uphill. Yet 2 or 3 ones going downhill can create by recuperation enough energy for one going uphill.

Answer (score 1):

#### A Graph

I haven't seen this graph anywhere, so I thought it would be interesting to draw it. Consider a simple reversible reaction:

$$
\ce{A <=>[k_\text{f}][k_\text{b}] B}
$$

| Time | $\ce{[A]}$ | $\ce{[B]}$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $0$ | $1$ | $0$ |
| $t$ | $1-\xi$ | $\xi$ |
| $t_\text{eq}$ | $\dfrac{k_\text{b}}{k_\text{f}+k_\text{b}}$ | $\dfrac{k_\text{f}}{k_\text{f}+k_\text{b}}$ |

Reaction quotient at time $t$ is defined as

$$
Q_\text{c} = \dfrac{\ce{[B]}}{\ce{[A]}}=\dfrac{\xi}{1-\xi} \tag{1}
$$

Forward and backward rates at time $t$ are given by:

$$
R_\text{f} = k_\text{f}\ce{[A]} = k_\text{f}(1-\xi); R_\text{b} = k_\text{b}\xi \tag{2}
$$

From Equations (1) and (2):

$$
R_\text{f} = \dfrac{k_\text{f}}{Q_\text{c}+1}; R_\text{b} = \dfrac{k_\text{b}Q_\text{c}}{Q_\text{c}+1}
$$

[image: reaction rate vs reaction quotient]

You can play around with this [interactive plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pefgwxlu0u).

### Some More Clarification

There is a reason we draw the double, forward-backward arrow in $\ce{A <=>[k_\text{f}][k_\text{b}] B}$: it shows that the **reaction proceeds in both directions simultaneously**.

1. When $Q_\text{c}<K_\text{c}$, forward reaction rate is greater than backward reaction rate:

$$
\ce{A <=>>[k_\text{f}][k_\text{b}] B}
$$

2. When $Q_\text{c}>K_\text{c}$, backward reaction rate is greater than forward reaction rate:

$$
\ce{A <<=>[k_\text{f}][k_\text{b}] B}
$$

#### Equilibrium Conditions

Equilibrium is achieved when forward and backward rates are equal:

$$
R_\text{f} = R_\text{b}\implies k_\text{f}\ce{[A]_\text{eq}} = k_\text{b}\ce{[B]_\text{eq}}\\
K_\text{c} = \dfrac{k_\text{f}}{k_\text{b}} = \dfrac{\ce{[B]_\text{eq}}}{\ce{[A]_\text{eq}}}
$$

#### Free Energy

Since both processes are spontaneous, $\Delta G$ for both processes, from nonequilibrium state to the equilibriums state, is negative. Free energy is *minimum* at equilibrium.